# UIWebview open new window

Tags: javascript, iphone, uiwebview, popup

I have a third party web page which dynamically creates a Form element and submits to new window...

Is there any way I can get informed that webpage opens new window?

here is the sample code.

```
function open_new_window(target){
      var postForm = document.createElement("form");
      postForm.setAttribute("name","printForm");
                  postForm.setAttribute("action","testpage?timeInMillis=" + new Date().getTime());
      postForm.setAttribute("target",target);
      postForm.setAttribute("method","post");

//other code....

      var parent = document.getElementById(parentId);
      parent.appendChild(postForm);
      postForm.submit();
      parent.removeChild(postForm);
    }
```

I have tried many ways and searched on - but didn't get any solution.

Comment: Do you want to intercept new window event on iPhone?

Comment: Yes. specially for the above code.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at UIWevViewDelegae, particularly, at

```
webView:shouldStartLoadWithRequest:navigationType:
```

here you can detect which URL webview is about to load and act accordingly.

Comment: How can i identify that it opens new window? Plz read my question again. Thanks

Comment: You need to know that some particular url opens new window. Get it from the browser, for example.

Comment: if there is two same url one has target defined then I cannot identify which one is clicked. plz read my question carefully.